# How to get index path for key - SWIFT?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new in Swift, so I have tableview and I need to get **index path** for key from firebase.
When row is clicked, I want to open a new controller where is displaying all data for that User (written in Firebase).

Here is my code for didSelectRowAt:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let selectedGuest = guestsList[indexPath.row]
    let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "GuestDetail") as! GuestDetailsViewController
    
    refGuests = Database.database().reference().child("userInfo").child(uid!).child("guests")
    refGuests.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        for snap in snapshot.children.allObjects as![DataSnapshot] {
            let uid = snap.key
            let guestD = snap.value as! [String:AnyObject]
            let guestN = guestD["guestPhoneNumber"] as! String
            print("key = \(uid) and tam = \(guestN)")
        }
    }
    
    controller.guestUser = selectedGuest
   self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. You have both the details for the selected guest, and the associated indexpath available in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how `selectedUser` is related to the fetched data but basically the order of the code is wrong.

As `observeSingleEvent` works asynchronously you have to instantiate and present the controller inside the completion closure. I suppose you have to check in the loop if `selectedUser` matches one of the records

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let selectedGuest = guestsList[indexPath.row]
    
    refGuests = Database.database().reference().child("userInfo").child(uid!).child("guests")
    refGuests.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        for snap in snapshot.children.allObjects as![DataSnapshot] {
            let uid = snap.key
            let guestD = snap.value as! [String:AnyObject]
            let guestN = guestD["guestPhoneNumber"] as! String
            print("key = \(uid) and tam = \(guestN)")
        }
        let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "GuestDetail") as! GuestDetailsViewController
        controller.guestUser = selectedGuest
        self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```